# Real field of definition of an abelian variety of CM-type?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, abelian-varieties, class-field-theory, complex-multiplication

> **Question 0.** Can a field of definitions (without automorphisms) of an (almost arbitrary) abelian variety of CM-type, originally defined over ${\mathbb{C}}$,
>   be chosen to be a totally real number field or at least a real number field?

I specify. Let $L$ be a CM-field of degree $[L:{\mathbb{Q}}]=2n$, i.e., a totally imaginary quadratic extension of a totally real number field.
Let $M$ be an order in $L$, for example, $M=O_L$, the ring of integers of $L$.
Let $\Phi$ denote the set of embeddings of $L$ into ${\mathbb{C}}$.
Let $\Psi$ be a CM-type for $L$, i.e., a subset $\Psi$ of $\Phi$ such that $\Phi$ is a disjoint union of $\Psi$ and $\overline{\Psi}$.
Here $\overline{\Psi}=\{\bar\varphi\ |\ \varphi\in\Psi\}$.
Then $|\Psi|=n$.
We embed the order $M$ into ${\mathbb{C}}^n$ using $\Psi$, then $M$ is a lattice in ${\mathbb{C}}^n$. We set $A={\mathbb{C}}^n/M$.
Then the complex torus $A$ is an abelian variety over ${\mathbb{C}}$, and we have an embedding $M\hookrightarrow{\mathrm{End}}\,A$.

**Question 1.** Is the field of moduli of $A$ *with endomorphisms from* $M$ a CM-field?

**Question 2.** Is the field of moduli of $A$ *without endomorphisms* totally real? If not, is it real, i.e., does it admit an embedding into ${\mathbb{R}}$?

**Question 3.** Can one choose a field of definition of $A$, *with endomorphisms from* $M$, to be a CM-field?

**Question 4.** Can one choose a field of definition of $A$ *without endomorphisms* to be totally real?
  If not, can it be chosen real, i.e., admitting an embedding into $\mathbb{R}$?